# Remove excessive zero on legend text using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I add the following code:

```
    scale_fill_continuous(limits=c(0.0001, 28),trans = "log", 
                           low = "green", high = "red",
                           breaks=c(0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1,3,10,25))
```

The text on legend should be

```
    (0.0001,0.0010,0.0100,0.1000,1.0000,3.0000,10.0000,25.0000)
```

How to remove the excessive zero on the text of legend?
How to make them as the following:

```
    (0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1,3,10,25)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `labels` argument to explicitly tell `ggplot2` to use those labels, i.e.:

```
 scale_fill_continuous(limits=c(0.0001, 28),trans = "log", 
                       low = "green", high = "red",
                       breaks=c(0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1,3,10,25),
                       labels=c("0.0001","0.001","0.01","0.1","1","3","10","25"))
```

Comment: On SO it is customary to click the green tick mark below the upvote counter to signal that the question has been answered, and/or upvote this answer.